# c# active directory temporary groupmembership?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, ttl, adgroup

Is there any way to add a user to a group for an exact time and then delete the user from the group automatically?
e.g.:
`CN=testuser1` and `CN=testgroup1`
Now I want to add the `CN=testuser1` to the `CN=testgroup1` for 1 day.
After that 1 day the user should leave(shouldn't be a member of the group anymore) `CN=testgroup1` **automatically**.
Is this possible with `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;`, `System.DirectoryServices;` or is there another solution except a Powershell script?

Hint: I don't want a solution with a powershell script or something like that. It should be done with in my c# program. I have a windows form where I have 3 textboxes:

- Username from AD: searches in the AD for a user (I already have a searcher)
- Groupname from AD: searches in the AD for a group (I already have a searcher)
- and duration: this is where I want to enter the duration how long the user should be in that group (in days)

When I press a button "Add user temporarily to group" the user should be added to that group for a specific time which I can enter in that duration textbox.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. It requires that you have a Windows Server 2016 forest and that you have the Privileged Access Management optional feature enabled.

Once you have this, you can specify a TTL for a linked value such as a group membership. This blog https://www.dsinternals.com/en/how-the-active-directory-expiring-links-feature-really-works/ shows you how to do this. I do not know if you can supply the syntax via ADSI (System.DirectoryServices) or if you will need to fall back to a direct LDAP call with System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.

Comment: So when I enable "PAM", then I am able to set such a path like this(?): <TTL=7200,CN=PatColeman,CN=Users,DC=adatum,DC=com>    when I add an user to a group right? Thanks for your link tho! @Brian Desmond

Comment: It would be nice if someone could actually provide a C# example.

Comment: Hello! A great solution for adding a user! BUT! How do I use C#/LDAP to get time counters from users in a group? As far as I understand, this value is not stored in the group? Is it hidden somewhere in the dark forest of AD?

Answer (score 2):

Brian answered the question - here's a C# example of how we've done this as requested by a comment on his answer.

```
using (GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName))
{
    TimeSpan span = accessUntil.Subtract(dtNow.Value);
    DirectoryEntry groupDirectoryEntry = (DirectoryEntry)group.GetUnderlyingObject();
    groupDirectoryEntry.Properties["member"].Add("<TTL=" + ((int)span.TotalSeconds).ToString() + "," + user.DistinguishedName + ">");
    groupDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
    groupDirectoryEntry.Close();
}
```

Note that the "Add" will replace the current TTL if one already exists for the member.