# C# Active Directory : get list temporary group membership?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I use the temporary (time-based) group membership mechanism in Active Directory for temporary user access to groups.

By means of Powershell, it is very easy to add users:

```
$ts = New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date) -End (Get-date).AddSeconds(50000)
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "mytest" -Members "kul" -MemberTimeToLive $ts
```

Then I can view the users and the remaining time and TTL:

```
(Get-ADGroup 'mytest' -Property member -ShowMemberTimeToLive).member
<TTL=49891>,CN=kul,OU=Company,DC=test,DC=local
```

How can I use C# / LDAP to add and view users with their counters?

1. Adding via C# has already been solved - [c# active directory temporary groupmembership?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054086/c-sharp-active-directory-temporary-groupmembership)
2. But how to implement viewing the remaining TTL time for users? In the response of paragraph 1, there was a link explaining about direct and reverse AD links. How to get this data correctly using `DirectoryEntry` or `GroupPrincipal`?

Comment: In the library  `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.dll` for `PowerShell` there is a mention of `public SwitchParameter ShowMemberTimeToLive { set => this["ShowLinkTtl"] = (object) value; get => this.GetSwitchParameter("ShowLinkTtl"); }` it remains only to understand how to pass this `ShowLinkTtl` switch to `DirectoryEntry` ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this page when looking for the PowerShell way to get the TTL of Group membership.

Yes, there is built in way,
`(Get-ADGroup 'mytest' -Property member -ShowMemberTimeToLive).member`.
But you must install RAST for Active Directory!

I built this app to show this property to all users, as I can't rely that RAST is installed on all workstations.

So based on the Example of "m33p" I paste here PowerShell Code to get the Membership TTL in Active Directory Groups.

## The Code

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols
$DC = [system.directoryservices.activedirectory.activedirectorysite]::GetComputerSite().servers[0].name
$groupDN = "CN=EX_ArchiveEstablish,OU=Exchange,OU=Applications,DC=sigal,DC=loc"
$LDAP_SERVER_LINK_OID = "1.2.840.113556.1.4.2309"
$showttlcontrol = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryControl($LDAP_SERVER_LINK_OID, $null, $true, $true);
$request = New-object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest
$request.Controls.Add($showttlcontrol);
$request.DistinguishedName = $groupDN;
$request.Scope = "Subtree" ;
# Get Just on attribute $request.Attributes.Add("member")
$request.Attributes.AddRange(@("member","displayname","memberof","samaccountname"));
$LdapConnection = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection($DC)
$response = $LdapConnection.SendRequest($request)
$enumerator = $response.Entries.GetEnumerator()
$Members = $response.Entries.GetEnumerator().attributes.member

for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $Members.Count ; $i++)
    {write-host ([String]$Members[$i])  }
```

Enjoy

Doron Zilber

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered this is part of a control search control that is provided in your search. 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2309 - LDAP_SERVER_LINK_TTL_OID

This is a quick example of its use in S.DS.P

```
var groupDN = "Your Group DN";

var showttlcontrol = new System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryControl("1.2.840.113556.1.4.2309", null, true, true);

var request = new SearchRequest();
request.Controls.Add(showttlcontrol);
request.DistinguishedName = groupDN;
request.Scope = SearchScope.Subtree;
request.Attributes.AddRange(new string[] { "member" });

var response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);
var enumerator = response.Entries.GetEnumerator();
if (enumerator.MoveNext() && enumerator.Current is SearchResultEntry entry) {
    var member = entry.Attributes["member"].GetValues(typeof(string)).Select(x => (string)x).FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(member);
}
```